# Clarification on directory structure for output and reference files

Tags: origen-sdk

In the default config/application.rb file there are some comments that could use some clarification.  Specifically, it says 'generally you want to setup the reference directory structure to mirror that of your output structure'.

```
  # By default all generated output will end up in ./output.
  # Here you can specify an alternative directory entirely, or make it dynamic such that
  # the output ends up in a setup specific directory. 
  config.output_directory do
    "#{Origen.root}/output/#{$dut.nick}/#{$dut.revision}"
  end

  # Similarly for the reference files, generally you want to setup the reference directory
  # structure to mirror that of your output directory structure.
  config.reference_directory do
    "#{Origen.root}/.ref/#{$dut.nick}/#{$dut.revision}"
  end
```

What is the actual consequence of not having a mirrored structure between the output and reference directories?

thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This advice is to ensure that you are always comparing like with like.

Say for example your application supported two flavors of some device, version 1 and version 2.

If you generated them both into `output/device` then you might start to loose track of which version of the patterns you have in that folder.
The normal approach then would be to modify `config.output_directory` to direct the patterns to `output/device/1` and `output/device/2`.

Now, if you didn't make the same change to the reference directory and it continued to compare to what is in `.ref/device` in both cases, then you could potentially run into problems if your device 1 output was compared against device 2 output that you had previously saved to the reference directory.

The advice therefore, is to keep the structure of both of these directories the same so that you are always comparing against previous output for the exact same target.

In some cases though, you might actually want both ouput dirs to compare to a single reference dir, i.e. if you expect that the output for the two targets would be the same and any difference would actually indicate that something has gone wrong.
For cases like that we give you independent control over both directories, but in the majority of cases they should just be setup to mirror each other.